# Не могу понять, почему цикл for не захватывает последнее слово строки

Tags: c++, строки

```
#include <string>
#include<set>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    string s;
    int a{ 0 },tp{ 0 },v{ 0 };
    string n{""},b{""};
    
    getline(cin, s);
    for(auto c:s) {
        a++;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i <= a; i++) {
        tp++;
        n = n + s[i];

        if (s[i] == ' ') {
         cout << n << endl;
            if (tp > v) {
                v = tp;
                b = n;
            }
            tp = 0;
            n = "";
        }
    }

    cout << b;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: 1. for(auto c:s) { a++; } - это что?  2. Давайте нормальные названия переменным, ничего же не понятно

Comment: Потому что последним символом строки может не быть пробел, и `if (s[i] == ' ')` не сработает на последнем слове. И еще - почему вы цикл называете алгоритмом? :)

Answer (score 2):

Потому что последним символом строки может не быть пробел, и `if (s[i] == ' ')` не сработает на последнем слове.

Если уж так хочется посимвольно слова собирать - то

```
int main()
{
    string s, n;
    if (getline(cin, s))
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < s.size(); i++)
        {
            if (s[i] == ' ')
            {
                if (n.size()) { cout << n << endl; n.clear(); }
            }
            else n += s[i];
        }

        if (n.size()) cout << n << endl;
    }
}
```

Но можно и короче -

```
string s;
if (getline(cin, s))
{
    istringstream ss(s);
    for(string n; ss >> n;) cout << n << endl;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Тут неопределенное поведение в `s[i]` при `i == a`.

Comment: Вообще-то нет. https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/operator_at - *If pos == size(), a reference to the character with value CharT() (the null character) is returned.*